# Counting occurrences of an intermittent event depending on start, end and frequency

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am sorry if this is a trivial question (I am really bad at math ;-)), but I cannot manage to find a convincing mathematical solution for it.

So, let's suppose events that occur intermittently along the days:

```
Event A occurs every 2 days, starts on day 1
Event B occurs every 2 days, starts on day 2
Event C occurs every 3 days, starts on day 3
etc.
```

Visually presented:

```
days 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
A    *   *   *   *
B      *   *   *   *
C        *     *
```

Now, I want to compute how many events of each observer will see, depending on the day they arrive and the day they leave.

Thus, I have the following variables:

```
event
  frequency:   1/2, 1/3...
  startingDay: 1, 2, 3...
observer
  firstDay:  1, 2, 3...
  lastDay:   6, 7, 8...
  totalDays = lastDay - firstDay + 1
```

Is there a formula that could easily compute for each observer how many events of each type he will see? I tried combining rounding (flooring totalDays*frequency) + some modulo, but I cannot seem to find the hang of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After decomposing the problem and trying every possible combination for a few days, I think I found the solution. At least, it seems to work for every possible case I can think of. It might be possible to reduce it, but at least, it works.

```
numberOfEventsSeen = ceil( (totalDaysOfObservation - ( (eventFrequency - (
    (dayOfArrival - 1 - eventStartingDay - 1) % eventFrequency) )
    % eventFrequency) ) / eventFrequency )
```

where

```
ceil() = ROUNDUP in Excel for instance
totalDaysOfObservation = dayOfDeparture - dayOfArrival - 1
eventFrequency = 2 (if event happens every 2 days), 3, etc.
```

(Note: sorry if this is by no means a normal mathematical notation ;-))